# Loop on all var in xslt

Tags: xslt, variables, foreach

I have some issue with Xslt syntax, my stylesheet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/">

<root>

<xsl:for-each select="for $x in(collection('file:///Users/admin/Documents/xmlSoapUi/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'))return saxon:discard-document($x)//testsuite"> 
 <ident>
    <xsl:value-of select="base-uri()"/>

 <xsl:if test="matches(base-uri(),'Catalog')">

    <xsl:call-template name="summaryCatalog"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="matches(base-uri(),'Status')">
    <xsl:call-template name="summaryStatus"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="matches(base-uri(),'Alarm')">
<xsl:call-template name="summaryAlarm"/>
</xsl:if>
 </ident>
</xsl:for-each>

</root> 

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="summaryCatalog">
    <xsl:variable name="avgAddFile" select="avg(testcase[@name='addFile']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgGetFile" select="avg(testcase[@name='getFile']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgRemoveFile" select="avg(testcase[@name='removeFile']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgAddGroup" select="avg(testcase[@name='addGroup']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgGetGroup" select="avg(testcase[@name='getGroup']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgRemoveGroup" select="avg(testcase[@name='removeGroup']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgAddMedia" select="avg(testcase[@name='addMedia']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgGetMedia" select="avg(testcase[@name='getMedia']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgRemoveMedia" select="avg(testcase[@name='removeMedia']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgAddMediaComponent" select="avg(testcase[@name='addMediaComponent']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgGetMediaComponent" select="avg(testcase[@name='getMediaComponent']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgRemoveMediaComponent" select="avg(testcase[@name='removeMediaComponent']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgAddOpus" select="avg(testcase[@name='addOpus']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgGetOpus" select="avg(testcase[@name='getOpus']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgRemoveOpus" select="avg(testcase[@name='removeOpus']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgAddTrack" select="avg(testcase[@name='addTrack']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgGetTrack" select="avg(testcase[@name='getTrack']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgRemoveTrack" select="avg(testcase[@name='removeTrack']/@time)"/>

    <testChargeCatalog>
    <avgAddFile><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddFile,'0.00000')"/></avgAddFile>
    <avgGetFile><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgGetFile,'0.00000')"/></avgGetFile>
    <avgRemoveFile><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgRemoveFile,'0.00000')"/>    </avgRemoveFile>
    <avgAddGroup><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddGroup,'0.00000')"/></avgAddGroup>
    <avgGetGroup><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddGroup,'0.00000')"/></avgGetGroup>
    <avgRemoveGroup><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddGroup,'0.00000')"/></avgRemoveGroup>
    <avgAddMedia><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddMedia,'0.00000')"/></avgAddMedia>
    <avgGetMedia><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddMedia,'0.00000')"/></avgGetMedia>
    <avgRemoveMedia><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddMedia,'0.00000')"/></avgRemoveMedia>
    <avgAddMediaComponent><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddMediaComponent,'0.00000')"/></avgAddMediaComponent>
    <avgGetMediaComponent><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgGetMediaComponent,'0.00000')"/></avgGetMediaComponent>
    <avgRemoveMediaComponent><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgRemoveMediaComponent,'0.00000')"/></avgRemoveMediaComponent>
    <avgAddOpus><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddOpus,'0.00000')"/></avgAddOpus>
    <avgGetOpus><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgGetOpus,'0.00000')"/></avgGetOpus>
    <avgRemoveOpus><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgRemoveOpus,'0.00000')"/></avgRemoveOpus>
    <avgAddTrack><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddTrack,'0.00000')"/></avgAddTrack>
    <avgGetTrack><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgGetTrack,'0.00000')"/></avgGetTrack>
    <avgRemoveTrack><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgRemoveTrack,'0.00000')"/></avgRemoveTrack>
    </testChargeCatalog>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="summaryStatus">
    <xsl:variable name="avgAddStatus" select="avg(testcase[@name='addStatus']/@time)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="avgGetStatus" select="avg(testcase[@name='getStatus']/@time)"/>
    <testChargeStatus>
    <avgAddStatus><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddStatus,'0.00000')"/></avgAddStatus>
    <avgGetStatus><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgGetStatus,'0.00000')"/></avgGetStatus>
    </testChargeStatus>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="summaryAlarm">
<xsl:variable name="avgAddAlarm" select="avg(testcase[@name='addAlarm']/@time)"/>
<xsl:variable name="avgGetAlarm" select="avg(testcase[@name='getAlarm']/@time)"/>
<testChargeAlarm>
<avgAddAlarm><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgAddAlarm,'0.00000')"/></avgAddAlarm>
<avgGetAlarm><xsl:value-of select="format-number($avgGetAlarm,'0.00000')"/></avgGetAlarm>
</testChargeAlarm>
</xsl:template>
```

what i want to do is create a template with an `<xsl:for-each select="AllVariables">`
and then apply some transform to the value of the variables.

I dont know if it is possible, because i haven't seen any exemple online.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me, why you can't do:

```
<testChargeCatalog>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="testcase" group-by="@name"> 
      <xsl:element name="avg{upper-case(
                                substring(
                                   current-grouping-key(),
                                   1,
                                   1
                                )
                             )
                            }{substring(current-grouping-key(),2)}">
         <xsl:value-of select="format-number(
                                  avg(current-group()/@time),
                                  '0.00000'
                               )"/>  
      </xsl:element>  
   <xsl:for-each-group>  
</testChargeCatalog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can (with XSLT 2.0 you seem to use) create one variable which is a sequence of several values and then you can use `for-each` to process that sequence of values. And of course you can create temporary results of nodes you can process further with for-each or apply-templates. So that is the approach you should choose, instead of declaring ten variable each having one value you either need to create one variable having a sequence of ten primitive values or you need to create a variable holding a temporary tree of XML nodes, then you can use apply-templates or for-each on those nodes in the temporary tree.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `xsl:variable` that is the union of all `xsl:variable` s in the `xsl:import`/`xsl:include` hierarchy starting from a primary stylesheet module.

However, you generally don't get *the values*,  you will only get the expression specified in the `select` attribute (or the body of the variable), but you will not be able to "get the values" due to the folowing main reasons;

1. It is not possible to dynamically evaluate any XPath expression in XSLT/XPath (version 1.0 and 2.0).
2. Even if dynamic evaluation were possible (say in version 3.0), it is not possible to re-create the dynamic context of an expression -- for example a variable is locally defined and uses other variables or parameters or context-dependent functions, such as `position()` or `last()`.